# Android IAB InvalidKeySpecException

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I use android IAB, It work perfectly on Nexus 5 but on asus zenfone I encounter error with following stacktracke

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:86)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:66)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:773)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:532)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:510)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:589)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:101)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
   at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:171)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:81)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:66)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:773)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:532)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:510)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:589)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.d2i_PUBKEY(NativeCrypto.java)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLKey.getPublicKey(OpenSSLKey.java:99)
   at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(OpenSSLRSAKeyFactory.java:47)
   at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:171)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.generatePublicKey(Security.java:81)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.Security.verifyPurchase(Security.java:66)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryPurchases(IabHelper.java:773)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:532)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper.queryInventory(IabHelper.java:510)
   at com.miskatmobile.android.almishbah.util.IabHelper$2.run(IabHelper.java:589)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

any idea why it happened?

thanks

Comment: When you generate a public key you pass in a key spec, and it looks like the system doesn't support that spec, so you could try a different one.  Not sure why you're generating a public key though.  More context might be helpful.

Comment: thanks, apparently it is my mistake, missing one character of public key for second build in zenfone